# Where to print a weekly black & white comic magazine

Tags: self-publishing, printing, magazines, comics, print-on-demand

Me and a couple of friends are thinking of creating a comic magazine that contains a couple of different original comics. This is what we want the magazine to have.

- All the images inside will be in black & white
- We want it to be printed on a 5 x 7.5(this is preferred) or 6 x 9 inch paper
- The paper has to be in a white or cream color paper
- It has to be printed on normal paper like the ones used in novels or something similar
- Each magazine will be around 100 pages

We will release one magazine a week or maybe one every two weeks. We need a website that prints them and ships them to us since we will be distributing them through a monthly subscription on our site. We don't want the printing website to distribute it themselves through ebooks, amazon, etc.

The only website that we found that might do everything we want is [diggypod](http://www.diggypod.com). Is there any other sites that will do everything we want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely check out [www.createspace.com](http://createspace.com)
That is Amazon's selfpublishing hardcopy arm. 
They have the sizes you are looking for and you can get your printed items done very inexpensively.

You can calculate your cost before you ever try the service if you go to:
https://www.createspace.com/Products/Book/?sitesearch_query=calculate%20cost&sitesearch_type=SITE#content7

[image]

Only $2.15 per copy even at low quantities.  You can't beat it.
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

If you have only found one company you seem to be searching in the wrong way. I would start with broad terms like 'printing services' and narrow it down by location (to reduce shipping) or something similar. I've done this is the past when I wanted books and magazines printed.

I've just tried it now and found a place two hundred metres away that would do the job and it was the second place listed.

If you use standard sizes (in this country A4 or A5) just about anywhere will do the job. If you use unusual sizes you might have to look a little further and it will cost you more.